# How get the flutter/dart build date time?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, gradle

I'm looking to display the build date of the Flutter/Dart app.

Is it possible ?

A possible solution for me it's to take Gradle res value : On Gradle/Android I can add this line in the `build.gradle` :

```
buildConfigField "long", "BUILD_TIME", System.currentTimeMillis() + "L"
```

But how I can get this in flutter part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would probably be a little bit complicated but still you can do that

1. So, what you need is add your field into the gradle as you did in question
2. Add next script

```js
import android.os.Bundle;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    new MethodChannel(this.getFlutterView(), "getFlavorConfiguration").setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {
        result.success(BuildConfig.FLAVOR_CONFIGURATION);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Where "getFlavorConfiguration" would be your new MethodChannel

3. In it's callback emit your `BuildConfig` value
4. And for iOS, modify `AppDelegate.m` like below and don't forget to add config fields to plist files

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  FlutterViewController* controller = (FlutterViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
  FlutterMethodChannel * channel = [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:@"getFlavorConfiguration"
                                                               binaryMessenger:controller];
  [channel setMethodCallHandler:^(FlutterMethodCall * _Nonnull call, FlutterResult  _Nonnull result) {
    NSString *flavorConfig = (NSString *) [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"FlavorConfiguration"];
    result(flavorConfig);
  }];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

5. Finally, Flutter code change :

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel("getFlavorConfiguration");
    channel.invokeMethod("method").then((result) {
      setState(() {
        _flavorConfig = result;
      });
    });
  }
```

In `InvokeMethod` you can put your string

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! And on iOS it's similaire ? Have you an example ?

Comment: Yep, there should be one, let me update the answer

Comment: @DevLoots I've updated example with iOS data